# Rails server error with strange symbols in requests.accepts: "[\"\\xE2\\x80\\x8B/\\xE2\\x80\\x8B\"]"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, ruby-on-rails-4, server, format

I routinely like to clean up 500 errors that come through Airbrake. I'm running a Rails 4.2.4 site in production and I get a recurring error which I'm finding quite puzzling.

The error is:

`Missing partial shared/_rhs with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>["\xE2\x80\x8B/\xE2\x80\x8B"], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :haml, :jbuilder]}.`

Looking at the env section of Airbrake for the error, the related section appears to be:

`"action_dispatch.request.accepts": "[\"\\xE2\\x80\\x8B/\\xE2\\x80\\x8B\"]",
  "action_dispatch.request.content_type": "",
  "action_dispatch.request.flash_hash": "",
  "action_dispatch.request.formats": "[\"\\xE2\\x80\\x8B/\\xE2\\x80\\x8B\"]",`

It looks like the browser (self-identifying as Chrome) is asking for an unrecognised format, but I have no idea why it would be doing so. It also seems to be asking for just the head.

I can just ignore it, but if anyone has any ideas as to why it occurs in the first place, I would be interested.

The full env (with identifying content items removed) is:

`{
  "DOCUMENT_ROOT": "[******]",
  "HTTPS": "on",
  "HTTP_ACCEPT": "​/​",
  "HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING": "gzip,deflate,sdch",
  "HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE": "en-US,en;q=0.8",
  "HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL": "no-cache",
  "HTTP_CONNECTION": "keep-alive",
  "HTTP_HOST": "[******]",
  "HTTP_PRAGMA": "no-cache",
  "HTTP_USER_AGENT": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.49 Safari/537.36",
  "ORIGINAL_FULLPATH": "[******]",
  "ORIGINAL_SCRIPT_NAME": "",
  "PASSENGER_APP_ENV": "live",
  "PASSENGER_APP_TYPE": "rack",
  "PASSENGER_SHOW_VERSION_IN_HEADER": "false",
  "PATH_INFO": "[******]",
  "QUERY_STRING": "",
  "REMOTE_ADDR": "[******]",
  "REMOTE_PORT": "47888",
  "REQUEST_METHOD": "HEAD",
  "REQUEST_URI": "[******]",
  "ROUTES_40753200_SCRIPT_NAME": "",
  "ROUTES_48254480_SCRIPT_NAME": "",
  "SCGI": "1",
  "SCRIPT_NAME": "",
  "SERVER_ADDR": "[******]",
  "SERVER_NAME": "[******]",
  "SERVER_PORT": "443",
  "SERVER_PROTOCOL": "HTTP/1.1",
  "SERVER_SOFTWARE": "nginx/1.6.0",
  "action_dispatch.cookies_digest": "",
  "action_dispatch.cookies_serializer": "",
  "action_dispatch.parameter_filter": "[\"password\"]",
  "action_dispatch.redirect_filter": "[]",
  "action_dispatch.remote_ip": "[******]",
  "action_dispatch.request.accepts": "[\"\\xE2\\x80\\x8B/\\xE2\\x80\\x8B\"]",
  "action_dispatch.request.content_type": "",
  "action_dispatch.request.flash_hash": "",
  "action_dispatch.request.formats": "[\"\\xE2\\x80\\x8B/\\xE2\\x80\\x8B\"]",
  "action_dispatch.request.parameters": {
    "action": "show_by_tag_and_slug",
    "controller": "[******]",
    "slug": "[******]",
    "tag": "[******]"
  },
  "action_dispatch.request.path_parameters": {
    "action": "show_by_tag_and_slug",
    "controller": "[******]",
    "slug": "[******]",
    "tag": "[******]"
  },
  "action_dispatch.request.query_parameters": "",
  "action_dispatch.request.request_parameters": "",
  "action_dispatch.request_id": "f120141c-58e6-4429-ad98-1ab352f1c7ce",
  "action_dispatch.show_detailed_exceptions": "false",
  "action_dispatch.show_exceptions": "true",
  "newrelic.transaction_started": "true",
  "preview_manager": "#<Preview::Manager:0x007fa334e8eca0>",
  "rack.hijack": "#<Proc:0x007fa34ee79020@/home/release/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/passenger-4.0.53/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:69 (lambda)>",
  "rack.hijack?": "true",
  "rack.multiprocess": "true",
  "rack.multithread": "false",
  "rack.request.query_hash": "",
  "rack.request.query_string": "",
  "rack.run_once": "false",
  "rack.url_scheme": "https",
  "rack.version": "[\"1\", \"2\"]",
  "warden": "Warden::Proxy:70169690063580 @config={:default_scope=>:user, :scope_defaults=>{}, :default_strategies=>{:user=>[:rememberable, :database_authenticatable]}, :intercept_401=>false, :failure_app=>#<Devise::Delegator:0x00000004e859a0>}"
}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The characters `\xE2\x80\x8B` seem to be the **[zero-width space character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm) in Unicode**. That's why, if you paste the string to ruby console, you'll get the following:

```
"\xE2\x80\x8B/\xE2\x80\x8B"
# => "​/​"
```

I.e. seemingly just the slash `/` but actually surrounded by two zero-width spaces. I have no clue why a browser would send such characters in the `Accepts` header, it might be a bug in the browser or even some kind of an attack...

Comment: Of course! It could be a random attack that just happens to break some servers. Rails is responding correctly though, thankfully. Thanks for the insight, have a green tick.

Comment: It seems to be either a bug or vulnerability of this specific Chrome version. We encountered the exact same accept header being sent by the exact same verison of Chrome (50.0.2661.49) 5 months later.

Comment: Thanks for the update Janosch, and good detective work. I'm still getting them fairly regularly, I'll double check the Chrome versions.

Comment: I can confirm than I'm also receiving the exact same Accept header from the same Chrome version 50.0.2661.49, so it seems like a bug from this specific browser.